# TaxJar method is not returning anything

Tags: php

I am using TaxJar integration in one of my projects to calculate the tax for an order. I have integrated TaxJar like this:

```
    $client = TaxJar\Client::withApiKey("8516090bdbb97d99632daa2acaf910aa30");

    $order_taxes = $client->taxForOrder([
        'from_country' => 'US',
        'from_zip' => '07001',
        'from_state' => 'NJ',
        'to_country' => 'US',
        'to_zip' => '07446',
        'to_state' => 'NJ',
        'amount' => 16.50,
        'shipping' => 1.5,
        'line_items' => [
            [
                'quantity' => 1,
                'unit_price' => 15.0,
                'product_tax_code' => 31000
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

When I do `var_dump($client)`, it shows all the details of the TaxJar dependencies which are included, but when I do `var_dump($order_taxes)` it shows nothing.

What should I do to get this work?

Comment: are you including the taxjar auto loader? I don't see it in the code?

Comment: yes i have included autoloader too

Comment: if that is your actual api key, i suggest you edit this to remove.

Comment: this is not the actual api key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API request should work correctly based on the information given. Please [see our response to your GitHub issue](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-php/issues/16) and reach out to TaxJar support with your account details for further assistance.